# .htaccess 301 rewrite rule not working

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had made the page the-book.html in wordpress site, later changed the name to about-the-book, now i have written the .htaccess file as

```
**RewriteRule ^the-book.html$ http://www.conversationissexy.com/about-the-book/ [R=301]**

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule> 

# END WordPress
```

but it doesn't works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Try adding `[L]` flag next to `R=301` -- right now redirect will not occur straight away and URL gets processed by other rules (the WordPress block). The `L` flag in conjunction with `R=3xx` tells Apache to execute such redirect immediately:

```
RewriteRule ^the-book.html$ http://www.conversationissexy.com/about-the-book/ [R=301,L]
```

This should do the job.

**2.** If still nothing -- move the above rule inside WordPress block and place just after RewriteBase line:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   # your redirect rule
   RewriteRule ^the-book.html$ http://www.conversationissexy.com/about-the-book/ [R=301,L]

   # actual WordPress rules
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

**3.** Alternatively, use `RedirectMatch` directive instead of `RewriteRule` so you can keep your redirect rule where it is right now:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/the-book.html$ http://www.conversationissexy.com/about-the-book/
```